# Private tags as a substitute for bookmarking

Tags: feature-request

I come across a wealth of information on these pages. To keep a record of useful or interesting topics I have to bookmark the links.

Does it make sense for users to have access to tagging questions/answers for their own private collection?

Comment: This exists in a very basic version: favoriting questions. You don't seem to be using this feature. More information on how it works is available at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work

Comment: [similar](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1905/14100)  It would be great to have a way to organize favorites.